# How from the Cell A, I can have the format S in a text file?

Tags: matlab, text-files

```
A = {[2    5],[4    8    9],[11   55    4    15],[89    2    47;4    25   10]}

S = {[2    5],[4    8    9],[11   55    4    15],[89    2    47],[4    25   10]}
```

How from the cell `A` `1x4`, I can have the format `S` with brackets and commas in the text file?

When opened in a text editor, the text file should look like:

```
{[2    5],[4    8    9],[11   55    4    15],[89    2    47],[4    25   10]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
A = {[2    5],[4    8    9],[11   55    4    15],[89    2    47;4    25   10]};

n=numel(A);

S{1} = strrep(['{' mat2str(A{1})  ], ';', '],[');

for i=2:n-1

    S{i} = strrep([',' mat2str(A{i})  ], ';', '],[');

end

S{n} = strrep([',' mat2str(A{n}) '}' ], ';', '],[');


dlmwrite('tmp.txt', S, '')
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your Cell array has not rectangular form (the first "row" entries have length 2, whilst the rest is longer), the conversion magic can't work.

Just write a bit of for loop that iterates over the cell array's elements, linearizes them (aka `matrix_variable(:)`) and prints out the result.

EDIT: since you asked for further details:
`doc cell` will show you an example of cell array usage, including reading its length and accessing elements. You can then just linearize your Cell array's elements (like illustrated above).